# Xamarin forms 3.0 force a specific orientation

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to know if there is any new way of handling to force a page to either landscape or portrait in xamarin.forms 3.0? I did manage to find some old articles on this but they refer to using methods that directly handle on each specific platforms. So, any new method in this xamarin.form 3.0?

```
These are my requirements:
1) Initially , all pages in iOS and Android are in Portrait Mode.
 Where and how to I set up this for iOS and Android?

2) How to I set up any page I want to display in Landscape mode when I click a button .
```

I saw this link with interesting approach using interface, But I dont understand how to use it.

[How to set ContentPage orientation or screen orientation on perticular page in Xamarin.Forms cross platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290561/how-to-set-contentpage-orientation-or-screen-orientation-on-perticular-page-in-x)
    Thanks

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. But, it's not too hard to create a `CustomView` and a `Custom Renderer` based on `ContentPage`, for example, and implement this like a property. Have you sawed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174715/8093394)?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, read the link. It seems the solution is target on a specific Page (in the example is ThirdPage) what if I need to do for other pages?

Comment: Still no way to do that out of the box. The [Selvarathinam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50673362/8093394)  is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can include below line of code in the MainActivity class in Xamarin.Droid.

```
[Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/AppTheme", Label = "App", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{}
```

This will force the app to stick with Portrait mode only. Hope this helps.

Comment: This code will fixed all pages in Portrait mode. I need to display some pages in Landscape mode after clicking a button. How to Achieve this? please see my update above.

Comment: You can use the answer provided by @mindOfAi. To do that, please watch this video which tells you the step by step approach on dependency service implementation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgcnYDb6cRQ