# Xamarin, block orientation of an element or view in a xaml page

Tags: xamarin, layout, locking, orientation

I have to design a page in Xamarin 5.0 where the bottom view should not rotate on device orientation. I could not find a way to just stop the orientation only for an element or view on the screen. This is something very similar to the camera view of an iPhone where you see the capture button and other icons at the bottom stays as is while the camera view rotates.

To demonstrate it better please see the page that was expecting to behave on portrait and landscape mode. The text USA stays as is, but Hello responds to orientation.

[image]

I tried many examples and all were about whole page orientation by detecting the device orientation using Xamarin Essentials or VisualStateManager.

Can we achieve this using xaml? Or using some part in code behind. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I learned that you cannot block the orientation of the element; hence accepting the answer already posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To demonstrate it better please see the page that was expecting to behave on portrait and landscape mode. The text USA stays as is, but Hello responds to orientation.

It seems that you can only lock the orientation of specific page, not the specific view or element.

MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "Portrait", sender =>
    {
        RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    });Sensor

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "Sensor", sender =>
    {
        RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Sensor;
    });
}
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Portrait");
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Sensor");
}
```

For more info, you can see this case: [Control single page orientation and view rotation in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447107/control-single-page-orientation-and-view-rotation-in-xamarin-forms).

I also searched other cases about it. You can refer to: [Xamarin Forms: allow rotation for some pages only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/619916/xamarin-forms-allow-rotation-for-some-pages-only), [How to set ContentPage orientation in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157585/how-to-set-contentpage-orientation-in-xamarin-forms).

Comment: Yes I have seen these examples. I'm hoping it should be possible because we see that in phones where we have a camera view like I mentioned.